# Can we reference teaser images in our papers?

Tags: paper-submission, graphics

The conference I'm submitting my paper allows for teaser images. I want to reference the teaser image in the text. Is this usually allowed? If it is, what is the standard way of referencing it? I mean, in regular figures we use \cref that results in something like Fig. 1. Should one just write "as we can see in the teaser image..."?

Comment: In the text of the main paper, it would be better not to refer to the teaser image. The paper should be self-contained and free of gimmicks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put the teaser image in the main paper? Or a figure with whatever you wanted to reference in the teaser?

Comment: What is a "teaser image"? Like a screenshot from a movie?

Comment: The paper is in Data Visualization. The conference suggests (recommends) the use of a teaser image. It is just an image right below the title, and in the first page.